# My badge not displaying properly

Tags: support, badges

What I have to do for get the **Curious** badge? There already is 5 out 5.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The Curious badge needs a positive question record. You don't have it (click on the tan area to see that).

Comment: I have 5 questions and all of them check as positive, also there displaying that 5/5 then I should get this badge, rigth?

Comment: From the [list of all badges with full description](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#67399): *A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5`.* Do you have deleted questions?

Comment: Deleted questions are not visible to most people but the system hasn't forgotten about them.

Comment: No. I do not have deleted. `No deleted recent questions`. Something strange. And what about the silver badge? Why it not display?

Comment: Maybe you have deleted non-recent questions?

Comment: Maybe yes, but I don't know how to check it.

Comment: So, finally I got a silver badge. But there remained the problem with Curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30946497/delphi-xe-and-unicode) with a down vote. As you have only 5 visible questions at this moment that down vote makes that you don't qualify for the rule:

> need positive question record

[image: curious badge showing no checkmark]

Comment: Ok, Thank you!! I just not see it